# Listview not getting generated as desired

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, hashmap

I have an activity where I want to generate a listview from an **Arraylist**, which is getting populated from a **Hashmap**. The list is getting generated, but only one item is showing in the list, its supposed to show two items.

This is the activity which is generating the **ListView**:

```
public class ExamNamesActivity extends Activity {
    TextView showUser;

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> acList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_exam_names);

    //assigning objects to layout
    showUser=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.exam_names_user_full_name_textView);
    //showing user's full name
    showUser.setText("Welcome, "+getFromPreference("user_name"));


    //------------------for list-----------------------------

    // creating new HashMap
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
    map.put("Name", "Online Speed Test");
    map.put("Name", "Practice Test");

    acList.add(map);


    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ac_list_listView);
      if (null != list && null != acList) {
       list.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(ExamNamesActivity.this,
         R.id.ListViewContainer, new String[acList.size()]));



      }


    }


    //class for the list and on click handler
    private class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private final Context context;
        private final String[] values;



        public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                String[] objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.context = context;
            this.values = objects;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent,
                    false);

            final HashMap<String, String> map =  acList.get(position);

            TextView textView = (TextView) rowView
                     .findViewById(R.id.list_label_name);
                     textView.setText(map.get("Name"));




            rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {

                    rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_bg_pressed);

                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_bg);

                        }
                    };
                    handler.postDelayed(r, 200);



//                           Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterFirstActivity.this, RegisterSecondActivity.class);
//                              
//                              intent.putExtra("AC_Code", map.get(TAG_CODE));
//                              RegisterFirstActivity.this.startActivity(intent);



                }
            });

            return rowView;

        }
    }





    //getting content from preferences
    public String getFromPreference(String variable_name)
    {
        String preference_return;
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        preference_return = preferences.getString(variable_name,"");

        return preference_return;
    }
  //method to show double button alert dialog
    public void twoButtonAlert(String title, String message, String button1, String button2)
    {

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ExamNamesActivity.this);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);

        // Setting Icon to Dialog
        //alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.delete);

        // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton(button1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

                // Write your code here to invoke YES event
                //goto login activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(ExamNamesActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                finish();
                ExamNamesActivity.this.startActivity(intent);


            }
        });

        // Setting Negative "NO" Button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton(button2, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Write your code here to invoke NO event
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();

    }


    }
```

This is the **layout of the activity**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".AdapterActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/exam_names_user_full_name_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Name Title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ListViewContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/exam_names_user_full_name_textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/ac_list_listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
        </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the layout for each row of the listview (**list_layout.xml**):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/library_linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/list_bg"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:background="@null" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_label_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The output is like this:

[image: Output]

**Why is the list not showing both the items? Where am I going wrong?**
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can not use same key name to store different values in HashMap. and if you do this then it will replace old value with new value on same key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your array list size, i.e you are adding only one hash map to that list. that's why your list showing only one item. then about your hash map, your adding two items with same key so that the second item overrides the first value. So change your code as follows

```
// creating new HashMap
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
    map.put("Name", "Online Speed Test");
    acList.add(map);

    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("Name", "Practice Test");
    acList.add(map);
```

Answer (score 2):

Its because you are using same key `"Name"` which is over-writing your first value. In Map when you put values with same key it over-writes.

Doing this,

```
map.put("Name", "Online Speed Test");
map.put("Name", "Practice Test");
```

Will retsult in only 1 value inside your map that is,

```
map.put("Name", "Practice Test");
```

while the first one is over-written.

Did you try to get the size of the map? you will get size as 1 not 2.

Comment: Then what should I do? How should I insert both the values and show both the values in listview?

Comment: give different keys like name, name1

Comment: and then how would I traverse?

Comment: you can simply get the values of map using `ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(map.values());` And pass this arraylist to your adapter

Comment: @kittu88 Please check my answer you get the idea

Comment: You can give key as "0" , "1" , "2" and in getView traverse it `map.get(""+position)` @kittu88

Comment: @kittu88 you can pass that ArrayList to your adapter and set the value inside TextView using `arrayList.get(position);`

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this steps

1. Create a HashMap object
2. put value in hashmap object
3. add hashmap to arraylist

Perform this steps for each item.

For Your case. It Should like this

```
HashMap<String, String> map;

map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("Name", "Online Speed Test");
acList.add(map);

map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("Name", "Practice Test");
acList.add(map);
```